# Facebook authorisation: Handeling cancellation

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, fbconnect

I am building an app, which uses facebook authorisation services. However, I am facing problems in two cases

1. The user is sent to the facebook app for giving permission. Instead, she presses the home button and again opens my app. 
   In this case, I need to do two things:
   a. Re-show her the login page (and remove the animation from that page): For this I need to know that the user has come back to the app without logging into fb.
   b. Cancel the last request sent to fb: If user tries to login again, my app sends two requests to the fb authorisation system, which leads to two popup windows in the fb app and also gives back multiple calls to my app.
2. The user presses the cancel button: In this case fb app is not re-directing to my app. I read that this was a bug and has been fixed; however, this still this does not work for me. Any suggestions?

I have tried to search for similar Q on the forum; however, have not been able to find exact answer. Please let me know if I missed looking at relevant question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS, then

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
```

}

Will cancel the auth request if the user happened to cancel the auth flow via doing something like hitting the Home button. You can then reset by showing your login view again.

The (2) problem should be fixed if you upgrade to the latest Facebook iOS app.

Comment: Thanks! What would work for sdk 3.0? Currently, I am doing the following: Check in appdelegate's applicationdidbecomeactive if the FBSession state is FBSessionStateCreatedOpening. If yes, then reset the activeSession with required permission set. This step changes the state of FBSession to FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed and calls the completion handler (as the state has changed). Check for FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed state in the completion handler and reset the interface accordingly. However, this looks more like a hack and i would be happy to use a better method.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to move to 3.1? Then you could rely on the non-hacky way.

Comment: I will eventually move to 3.1, just that, I have already coded everything and do not have enough time to change.

Comment: For 3.0, try this: - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // this means the user switched back to this app without completing a login in Safari/Facebook App
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {
        [FBSession.activeSession close]; // so we close our session and start over
    }
}